# How to play videos randomly?

Tags: java, android, arrays, random, media-player

I want to create an app that play 3 videos one by one in random order from a ArrayList. First I would like to know how to play videos continiously one by one and then randomly. I did research on the internet but despite several techniques and attempts I did not achieve the result.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Random rand = new Random();
    private VideoView videoView;
    static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Integer> WaitingArray = new ArrayList<>();

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        WaitingArray.add(0, R.raw.d41);
        WaitingArray.add(1, R.raw.d42);
        WaitingArray.add(2, R.raw.d43);


        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), WaitingArray.get(i));

    }
}
```

You can see that i have created a list with 3 videos. But I don't know what to do to play them randomly or at least in order with the media player.

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I sadly can't help you with the task of playing videos continuously.

But for your problem of randomizing the List here are some some food for thought. If you have a collection `col` you can use `Collections.shuffle(col)` to shuffle their entries.

```
List<Integer> waitingArray = new ArrayList<>();

waitingArray.add(R.raw.d41);
waitingArray.add(R.raw.d42);
waitingArray.add(R.raw.d43);
Collections.shuffle(waitingArray);
```

That might suffice if i would need a list of three entries shuffled for a single usage.

Taking into consideration your other problem of looping the videos I could imagine that you would want your list of video continue in an unpredictable manner.

One way would be to create a bag of all possible videos and shuffle it an pull the elements one by one, until the bag is empty. And only then refill it randomly again. This is how the [tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) [modern versions of Tetris](http://www.nintendoworldreport.com/interview/11267/tetris-from-the-top-an-interview-with-henk-rogers) are distributed.

```
public class RandomBag<T>
{
    private final Collection<T> sources;
    private List<T> currentBag = Collections.emptyList();

    public RandomBag(Collection<T> sources)
    {
        this.sources = sources;
    }

    public synchronized T get()
    {
        if (currentBag.isEmpty())
        {
            createNewBag();
        }
        currentBag.get(0);
    }

    private void createNewBag()
    {
        currentBag = new ArrayList<>(sources);
        Collections.shuffle(currentBag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vala. D , but can you tell me how to add the path of the video in media player please ?